# Saving page in backend results in 404 on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, backend, 404-page

I'm working on a Magento 1.9.x project initially build by another developer. Now, when I save a customer group in the backend, I get redirected to the frontend resulting in a 404 page. It happens with some other forms in the backend.

At this point I don't have the time nor a clue how to fix this :/

Anyone an idea how this might be caused?

Comment: have you found any solution for this issue?

Comment: I have found problem solution.In my server mod rewrite is off and due to that its not working. Once my server support enabled mod rewrite it works for me. I hope it will help you and other also

Answer (score 2):

sometimes in case of error would end up in a 404 so check your logs for more information or just debug to see who is redirecting to 404. it might be that the action being called isn't found. for sure no fast fix for this kind of error.